# initialize youtube player fragment within a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtubeplayer

I am trying to initialize youtubeplayer fragment within a fragment. I successfully implemented the fragment within an activity but getting problem to initialize it in a fragment.
the code snippet for activity is as below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX youTubePlayerFragment;  


 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initializeYoutubePlayer();

private void initializeYoutubePlayer() {

        youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_player_fragment);


        if (youTubePlayerFragment == null)
            return;

        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(Constants.DEVELOPER_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
                                                boolean wasRestored) {
                if (!wasRestored) {
                    youTubePlayer = player;


                    //set the player style default
                    youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);

                    //cue the 1st video by default
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(youtubeVideoArrayList.get(0));

                    youTubePlayer.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {

                //print or show error if initialization failed
                Log.e(TAG, "Youtube Player View initialization failed");
            }
        });
    }
```

To convert this code into fragment, I tried this

```
public class Welcome extends Fragment {
  private YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX youTubePlayerFragment;
   private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_welcome, container, false);
 initializeYoutubePlayer();

private void initializeYoutubePlayer() {
       youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_player_fragment);

        if (youTubePlayerFragment == null)
            return;
        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(Constants.DEVELOPER_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
                if (!wasRestored) {
                    youTubePlayer = player;


                    //set the player style default
                    youTubePlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT);

                    //cue the 1st video by default
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(youtubeVideoArrayList.get(0));

                    youTubePlayer.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE);
                }

            }


            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Youtube Player View initialization failed");
            }
        });

    }

    private void getSupportFragmentManager() {
    }
}
```

but getting error in finding the fragment layout. Can somebody guide me how to do this in fragment? The layout for Welcome fragment is as follows

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FCFDFF"
    tools:context="com.currentmedia.channelslayout.Welcome">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        app:title="Punjabi News Live"
        app:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF" />

 
    <!--  Youtube Player Fragment  -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/adView"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="#ccc"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/youtube_player_fragment"
            android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your layout, instead of using a < fragment > you should use a < FragmentContainerView > and replace the fragment in your activity using transaction.

Here is a tutorial if you're new with manipulating fragment in 2020:

[FragmentContainerView explanation](https://proandroiddev.com/android-fragments-fragmentcontainerview-292f393f9ccf)